# Почта (OpenCart)

Tags: email, php, smtp

Добрый вечер. Обнаружил что мне не приходят письма с обратной связи на сайте. Обратился к хостеру, там сказали что все должно работать, мол smtp у них включен. После этого я поставил в настройках почты smtp вместо mail. В поле "SMTP хост" вписал smtp.yandex.ru (почта у меня на яндексе). В поле логин и пароль вписал почту и пароль к ней. Теперь вылетает ошибка

Notice: Error: MAIL FROM not accepted from server! in /var/www/mahgo4/data/www/fishing-trade.com/system/library/mail.php on line 290

Очень прошу о помощи. Перерыл кучу тем не форумах - ответа не нашел. Заранее очень благодарен.

Comment: smtp.yandex.ru не надо, попробуйте localhost

Comment: Ответил на сайте конкуренте)

Answer (score 1):

1. Уберите в админке smtp.yandex.ru , оставьте smtp или mail.
2. Если это стандартная форма со страницы контактов - проверьте куда и какие данные уходят при сабмите формы. Они уходят постом, так что отловить их не сложно. В контроллере:
   **controller\information\contact.php**
   посмотрите что приходит. там же формируется письмо (строчка 10):

   ```
   if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
       $mail = new Mail();
       $mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
       $mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
       $mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config-  >get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
       $mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
       $mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
       $mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
       $mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config-    >get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');
       $mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
       $mail->setFrom($this->request->post['email']);
       $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($this->request->post['name'],     ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
       $mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode(sprintf($this->language->get('email_subject'), $this->request->post['name']), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
       $mail->setText($this->request->post['enquiry']);
       $mail->send();
       $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('information/contact/success'));
   ```

   }

Проверьте, может не доходит какой-то параметр из конфигов во время формирования объекта.